# Bug in ASP.NET Identity's UserManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

MVC5's UserManager seems to have a bug:

My Code:

```
public void InsertUser(KoreUser user, string password)
{
    var appUser = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Email = user.Email,
        LockoutEnabled = user.IsLockedOut
    };
    userManager.Create(appUser, password);
}
```

THis code works perfectly fine in almost all cases.. the exception being when the UserName contains a space.. for example:

**JohnDoe - fine**

**John Doe - not fine..**

In the latter example, it silently fails; no exception thrown.. what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a bug. An exception isn't thrown because it's reasonable to expect an invalid username in the land of user authentication.

The default check done when creating a username uses regex pattern `^[A-Za-z0-9@_\.]+$` to validate the name before creating the user. A whitespace character doesn't pass this test.

Another note is that the `Create` method of Usermanager returns an object of type [IdentityResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Using that object you can check for success and see what errors are being returned in the event that a user is not created.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although I was aware of the reasoning behind not allowing a space (it is a username, after all and not the user's real name), I did think it rather odd that no exception was thrown.. thanks for the tip about the IdentityResult.

Comment: Generally exceptions aren't thrown unless something exceptional happens. Instead objects are used to represent the state of the operation.